# Type Error argument 1 needs to be a iterator

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to copy data over from my filteredData.csv to my average2016.csv which I have done, but when I'm going through and trying to split the date I'm getting

```
File 
"U:/CISP253/Final/test", line 9, in <module>
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
TypeError: argument 1 must be an iterator
>>>
```

as my error.

```
import shutil
import csv
import collections
with open("filteredData.csv", "wb") as csvfile:
    csvfile.close()

with open("average2016.csv", "w") as csvfile2:
    shutil.copyfile('filteredData.csv', 'average2016.csv')
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile2, delimiter=',')
    result = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for row in readCSV:
       year = row[1].split("-")[0]
       result[year].append(row)

    csvfile2.close()
```

I made the change to readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile2, delimiter=',') that was necessary and that was to turn csvfile to csvfile2 as was mentioned.
Also is this the best way to go about splitting the date?

Thank you

Comment: `csvfile` is still in scope, it's just closed.

Comment: @JeffMercado yeah, just to elaborate on kindall's comment, Python doesn't have block scope, which can be weird to a lot of people.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: oh, oops, mixing up scoping rules in my head, thanks for bringing me on the loop

Comment: Please **do not edit your question** to reflect the answer you have been given. It is just confusing for other Seekers who need to understand your initial problem and hence why the accepted answer is correct. If you have a further question please ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to change to `csvfile2`

```
with open("average2016.csv", "w") as csvfile2:
    shutil.copyfile('filteredData.csv', 'average2016.csv')
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile2, delimiter=',')
```

Comment: Alright by doing that it created File "U:/CISP253/Final/test", line 11, in <module>
    for row in readCSV:
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable

Comment: Well you opened it in `'w'` which is write mode. Try `'r'` for read

Comment: So it should be a 'r' then? I figured it would be a 'w' because I will be writing data to that file.

Comment: Where do you actually write to that file?

Comment: Actually now that I ran it I realized I never have anything written to it and it doesn't copy over the data from filteredData.csv.

Comment: Then I guess what did I do wrong with copying of the files? Or do I need to create a new question for that?

Comment: I can edit my answer, but i'm not 100% on what you were trying to do

Comment: It's alright I'l do some looking around and see what I can find thank you for your help.